# Better optimized version of the below SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, union

Currently I have created this SQL query:

```
select "Col1",
       "Col2",
       max(Col3) as "Col3"
  from (select Col1, Col2, 0 as "Col3" 
          from table1
         where col1='abc'

        union

        select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) as "Col3"
          from table1,
              (select table1.col1, count(table2.Col3) 
                 from table1, table2 
                where table1.col1 = table2.col1 
                group by table1.col1) 
      ) All_Records
where ALL_Records.Col1 = 'abc'
group by "Col1", "Col2"
```

Is there a better way to optimize the sql select statement, I want to get the max value because if I don't use I would end up with 2 rows for same row with 0 (hardcoded) and the other value returned by the logic.

**Problem Statement:** I want to retrieve the number of times the salary has changed for the employees, 
I am using the union to get the records where there is entry in `SALARY_HISTORY` table, if there are no rows in `SALARY_HISTORY` display 0.

```
select "EMPID",max(SALARY_CHANGE_RECORDS.Salary_Change_Count)
    select EMP.ID as "EMPID",SALARY_CHANGE.Change_Count as "Salary_Change_Count"
    from 
    EMP,
    (select EMP.ID, COUNT(SALARY.Salary_Change_ID) as "Salary_Change_Count"
        from EMP, SALARY_HISTORY  where EMP.ID=SALARY_HISTORY.ID group by EMP.ID
    union 
    select EMP.ID, 0 as "Change_Count"from EMP) SALARY_CHANGE_RECORDS
group by "EMPID"
```

Comment: I think you should explain what you are trying to do.  I think your query can be significantly improved; the problem is figuring out what it is doing.  For instance, it is not even syntactically correct.

Comment: ok, the problem statement is 

1. the second union record set would not fetch the values if the join operation results in no record set, hence

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definitions of the tables involved, including any indexes. Some sample data would be very helpful. A functioning SQLFiddle would be best. Thanks.

Comment: do you understand there is a cross join in there?

Comment: Do you need UNION's duplicate row removal, or can you just use the faster UNION ALL?

Comment: updated the question to get better understanding of the problem statement.

I want to get all items with the count of changes made in the salary for employee.

I hope now the question makes more sense about wht I want to achieve.

Comment: @jarlh I need the duplicate row removed and display only the row which is greater than 0, if there is only 1 row per ID with value as 0, display only this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this would work:

```
select    emp.id,
          count(salary_history.Salary_Change_ID)
from      emp
left join salary_history on emp.id = salary_history.id
group by  emp.id
```

It just counts the number of salary_history records.

Comment: thanks, this worked, why dint I think of using a left join earlier :)